# Use a variable from a function to a dictionary

Tags: python, function, dictionary

Can someone help me to solve this problem. I tried to search for an answer but I couldn't find one

```py
def thAnalysis(direction):
    # thAnalysis(<direction>) Time History Analysis Direction in <vertical>, <horizontal>, <both>
    both = {
        "folder": "VHGM",
        "title": "Horizontal + Vertical",
        "plot": "Horizontal + Vertical GM plot"}
    vertical = {  # done
        "folder": "VGM",
        "title": "Vertical",
        "plot": "Vertical GM plot"}
    horizontal = {
        "folder": "HGM",
        "title": "Horizontal",
        "plot": "Horizontal GM plot"}

    print(direction["folder"])
```

I call the function as

`thAnalysis('horizontal')`

and I get this error

```py
print(direction["folder"])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Thank you for you help

Comment: the variable `direction` is not a dictionary, it's the `'horizontal'` string.

Comment: What is your goal? Are you trying to select one of the tree dictionaries?

Comment: what is the purpose of `thAnalysis` ?

Comment: thAnalysis() is a function I wrote to perform a Time History Analysis (Earthquake Engineering). The code I shared was just a part of a long code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example `direction` is the string "horizontal", not the dictionary in the variable named `horizontal`. Instead of putting your dictionaries in local variables, put them in an outer `dict` that will map the string name to the `dict` you want.

```
def thAnalysis(direction):
    # thAnalysis(<direction>) Time History Analysis Direction in <vertical>, <horizontal>, <both>
    directions = {
        "both": {
            "folder": "VHGM",
            "title": "Horizontal + Vertical",
            "plot": "Horizontal + Vertical GM plot"},
        "vertical": {  # done
            "folder": "VGM",
            "title": "Vertical",
            "plot": "Vertical GM plot"},
        "horizontal": {
            "folder": "HGM",
            "title": "Horizontal",
            "plot": "Horizontal GM plot"}
    }

    if direction not in directions:
        print("invalid input")
    else:
        print(directions[direction]["folder"])

thAnalysis("horizontal")
```